# Could not reference F# library from C# web project in .NET 4.6?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-4.6

In the past, I was used to do the reference from my C# web project to my F# library project (I wrote it), and that worked well. But now when I moved to .NET 4.6, I did the same thing, but I could not make it work. It always notified `The following projects are not supported as references: <My F# library>`. I got stuck on this issue in couples of days. Could anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a guess (that's probably silly because you added the mvc tag but): are your C# stuff *UWP* ? (this sadly - not yet - supports F#)

Comment: Thanks for your very quick reply. But actually I am not use UWP stuff. I am only want to leverage the FParsec F# lib to parsing some text in my project. So that a reason I want to use F# lib in my C# web solution. Do we have another solution?

Comment: I guess it's possible that I did not try it on 4.6 yet but this really *should* work - can you write a bit more about your setup (cpu architecture, F# compiler version, ...?)

Comment: I used "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x64"
  } architecture config, and F# 4.4.0.0 version

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same problem. I'm using .NET 4.6 and F# Core 4.4. I tried to reference a F# class library on a ASP.NET 5 project and it didn't work. The error message was the same you mention. The only way to make a MVC project recognize F# is to use the latest stable version, ASP.NET 4.6.

For me, it seems that the new .NET Core stuff does not support yet the F# Class Libraries. I hope to see this working soon!